# set with measure invariant under translation has 0 or full measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ Lebesgue measurable such that $\mu(A\backslash{}A+x)=0$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Show that $\mu(A)=0$ or $\mu(\mathbb{R}\backslash{}A)=0$.

Since $A+x$ is measurable I can conclude that $\mu(A)=\mu(A\cap{}A+x)+\mu(A\backslash{}A+x)=\mu(A\cap{}A+x)=\mu(A+x)$.

In fact for every measurable $I$ we have that $0=\mu(A\backslash{}A+x)=\mu((A\backslash{}A+x)\cap{}I)+\mu((A\backslash{}A+x)\backslash{}I)=\mu((A\cap{}I)\backslash{}((A+x)\cap{}I))$ which for $\mu(I)<\infty$ gives $\mu((A+x)\cap{}I)=\mu(A\cap{}I)$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ or equivalently $\mu(A\cap{}(I+x))=\mu(A\cap{}I)$.

Taking $I=(0,1)$ we have that $\mu(A)=\mu(\cup_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}A\cap{}(I+n))=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\mu(A\cap{}I)$ and thus if $\mu(A)<\infty \implies \mu(A)=\mu(A\cap{}I)=0$.

I cannot handle the case $\mu(A)=\infty$. Is my proof above correct?
How can I proceed?

Comment: In your first line you get $\mu (A)=\mu (A\cap (A+x))$ which cannot be written as $\mu (A+x)$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy $\mu$ is translation invariant as it is the Lebesgue measure

Answer (score 1):

This requires  a more careful analysis when $\mu (A)=\infty$.

Let $\mu (B) <\infty$.  We have $\int_{B \cap A} 1 dy= \int_{B \cap A} I_{A+x} (y) dy$ for every $x$ since $B\cap A \setminus B \cap A \cap (A+x) \subset A \setminus (A+x)$. Since $I_{A+x} (y) \leq 1$ this implies $I_{A+x} (y)=1$ for almost every $y \in B \cap A$ and this is true for every $x$. By a standard Fubini argument we can now conclude that for almost every $y \in B\cap A$ we have $I_{A+x} (y)=1$ for almost every $x$. If $\mu (B  \cap A) >0$ the there is at least one $y$ for which $I_{A+x} (y)=1$ for almost every $x$.  But this implies that $\mu (\mathbb R \setminus A)=0$. Now apply this to $B=(-n,n)$ and vary $n$ to finish the proof.

Comment: Apologies but I don't see it: How does the existence of a $y\in{}A\cap{}B: y\in{}A+x$ for almost all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ imply $\mu(\mathbb{R}\backslash{}A)=0$?

Comment: @mrinwhite $y \in A+x$ for almost all $x$ means there exists a set $E$ of measure $0$ such that $x \notin E$ implies $y \in A+x$ or $y-x \in A$. Let $F=y-E$. Then $F$ has measure $0$. If $z \notin F$ then $y-z \notin E$. This implies $y-(y-z) \in A$ or $z \in A$. So $\mathbb R \setminus F \subset A$ or $\mathbb R \setminus A \subset F$ which implies $\mathbb R \setminus A$ has measure $0$.